# XCode TableView TextFields entering data odd behaviour

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Yesterday I asked this question here

[iPhone TableView with TextFields - next, previous button issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063798/iphone-tableview-with-textfields-next-previous-button-issue)

which was regarding an issue I had with the next previous buttons. Thankfully I got that sorted. Now the problem I am having is how the data is being saved to the text fields. You can recreate this problem yourself pretty quickly, create a new project, and have a view controller which contains a tableview. Then create a custom tableview cell which contains a label and a text field, then make this table have say 10 cells.

So if you enter some random text in the very first text field, then scroll down to the bottom of the table, what happens is that one of the text fields that will get loaded into memory will appear with the same text as the first text field, and if you scroll up and down really fast, the text keeps jumping between text fields and sometimes the text in the first textfield you entered will have disappeared and appeared in the 2nd or 3rd cell instead.

Example I entered test1 into the first text field and it appears fine like this

[image]

Then when I scroll down, the text field in cell 8 also has the exact same text for some reason

[image]

As a work around I tried adding this code to my custom tableview cell class that I was shown yesterday, I added a string object called sData and when user is finished editing that text field, the text is stored to that object.

```
  #pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
        self.sData = inputOne.text;

        if (self.didEndEditingAction) {
            self.didEndEditingAction();
        }
```

I also added this method to the custom table view cell class

```
    - (void)reloadData {

        if(self.sData != nil)
        {
                self.inputOne.text = self.sData;
        }
```

And then calling this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but same problem occurs.

This is causing me several issues, mainly trying to save the data as if the cell containing the text field is not visible on the screen then it is not loaded into memory and thus I cannot save the data for the text field. And of course the other problem is that the text in the field keeps disappearing and reappearing in different cells for some reason.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and if there are any good work arounds for this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

One thing I tried which I thought would work even though wasn't great solution was I created an array,  and under the textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method, I did this

```
BOOL bAdd = YES;
    for(int i = 0; i < [tableArray count]; i++)
    {
        UITextField *field = [tableArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if(field.tag == textField.tag)
        {
            bAdd = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(bAdd)
    {
        NSLog(@"Adding %i", textField.tag);
        [tableArray addObject:textField];
    }
```

Then under cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I added this

```
for(int i = 0; i < [tableArray count]; i++)
            {
                UITextField *field = [tableArray objectAtIndex:i];
                if(field.tag == cell.textField.tag)
                {
                    cell.textField.text = field.text;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I thought this was guaranteed to work, but same odd issues are happening and I have no idea why :@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to this, I created a NSMutableDictionary variable, and under the text field textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method I stored the value of the text field with the key being the text fields tag like so

```
[textFieldDictionary setValue:textField.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", textField.tag]];
```

Then under cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I put this

```
if([textFieldDictionary valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cell.textField.tag]])
            {
                cell.textField.text = [textFieldDictionary valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cell.textField.tag]];
            }
```

Now it works perfectly!!

Comment: HiAdam.....I am also struggling with the same issue.I have multiple Sections with 2 rows.Then how will i save UITextfield data while scrolling UITableview.

Comment: I thought my answer explained it. I used a dictionary to store the data in. So under textFieldDidEndEditing, everytime they enter something, it is stored in the dictionary using the textField tag as the Key. When if they scroll down and then back up again, when cellForRowAtIndexPath method is called as the cell is loaded back into memory. It then checks to see if anything is stored for that key, and if it is, use that data to populate the textField

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because the tableview "reuses" its cells. As you well may be knowing, you use this method `– dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`
in `– cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and it reuses the cells.

What you want to do is reset those text fields texts to nil just before reusing. To do that, you can use the following method,

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
     //Set whatever you want to be reset to nil E.g., myTextfield.text = nil;
}
```

Write that method in your custom table view cell class and that should solve the problem..!

Good luck.!

Comment: I set the text to @"" in that prepareForResuse method. That solves the reuse problem however now when I enter text into a text field and scroll down so the cell is off the screen, then scroll back up, the text field is now empty

Comment: Yes, it will become empty, you are setting it to empty string right..?? So what you do is, in textDidEndEditing of the textField, save the text into a property, and in the cellForRowAtIndexpath set the text from the property. Wouldn't it solve your problem..?

Comment: I have done that, but the same problem is happening which is what I do not understand, I have a property in the custom tableview class called sData and when text field is done editing I save the data to that property, and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, I then set the text field to that property, but for again, say I enter data in textfield one, then scroll down quickly, that data wil appear in cell 7 or 8. And if I scroll up again quickly sometimes it will disappear from cell 1 and appear in cell 2 or 3 randomly

Comment: Well, what I think, the way to implement wat you want is as follows. You should have a Model, And the delegate for the textfields need to be the controller. The controller in the delegate method (textDidendEditing) will set the data (or property) in the  model.In cellForRowAtIndexpath you retrieve the data from the model  and set it to the cell. If you do that, I bet it has to work..!